# PDO returing new ID error

Tags: php, pdo

My question today is that I'm trying to return an id after I inserted a new line into my DB.

```
    $sql = ('INSERT INTO `tSections`(`sSection`, `pCity_id`) VALUES (:sSection, :pCity_id) RETURNING pSection_id');  
$new_section = $DBH->prepare($sql);
```

Without the returning pSection_id it works fine. Any ideas or solution. I'm assuming that I just forgot something simple.

Hope to hear from you guys soon.

This is the error that it gives

> Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'RETURNING pJob_Type_id' at line 1' in

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no such thing as `RETURNING` in MySQL.

You're looking for [`PDO::lastInsertID()`](http://il.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php).

Comment: Sorry I read to fast when I read what I thought was a solution.                        " I think I get a nice solution in Postgres to get the ID using the RETURNING that comes with Postgress since version 8.2. In the example below, I add to my insert clause the "returning" along with the primary key of my table, then after the execute, I do a fetch getting an array with the value of the last inserted id.

<?php
    public function insert($employee){

        $sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO employee(user_id,name,address,city) VALUES(:user_id,:name,:address,:city) RETURNING employee_id";"